# Javascript animation not smooth with embedded video

Tags: javascript, html, flash, redraw

I have a Vimeo video on a twitter bootstrap carousel. When I click the next button on the carousel, the animation lags a lot. This is probably because the embedded flash object redraws at a slower rate. Are there any workarounds for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a callback to your `next()` action that hides the vimeo and shows a static image or something. That will keep the redrawing from including the flash container.